IIS and AD trust - how it validates the user against DC
I have a user logged into domain A and an IIS server in domain B.
There is a two-way trust between these domains.
Now, the user from domain A enters the web app hosted on IIS in domain B using  windows integrated authentication.
Regardless the NTLM or Kerberos, will the IIS contacts directly with the user's domain "A" to validates the user's ticket, or will it send it to the domain "B" for DC to validate it? Or will it works completely different?
Thanks for clarification.

Have you tried this on your own to verify? Others can give you information on what should occur or you can also use Google to find out more about the scenario but the only way for you know what exactly will occur is to try it on your own as no one else has access to your infrastructure.

@NasirRiley I would like to know how it should works. Using Wireshark we found that it communicates directly with the user's AD, but we are not sure if this is because wrong trust configuration.

Then a Google search will turn up plenty of guides on how it is designed to function. People can give answers but they are just going to contain the same information. For the answer that has been given, you could have found that same information online. From what I said previously, the only way for you to determine what will actually work for you is to do it on your own which is what you'll have to do anyway.

For Kerberos inbound authentication, it is possible to perform PAC Validation, where the important bits (the Privilege Attribute Certificate) is validated. The PAC is where group memberships are stored. The flow path starts at the domain controller of the local endpoint "trusting" domain. This "validation" has traditionally not been mandatory, and at the resource member server receiving the request, there is a registry value to enable or disable the validation. That seems to be changing though, and may be enforced in the near future (2025), requiring validation.
Using NTLM, the endpoint domain local domain controller will forward the authentication request to the trusted domain. This can also occur transitively, if the trusting domain has an indirect trust with the trusted domain.
The authentication should succeed even if the endpoint does not have line of sight to a domain controller in the trusting domain.
How trust relationships work for forests in Active Directory - NTLM referral processing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/domain-services/concepts-forest-trust#ntlm-referral-processing
PAC Validation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-apds/1d1f2b0c-8e8a-4d2a-8665-508d04976f84
Active Directory Security Fundamentals - Kerberos PAC Validation
https://rootdse.org/posts/active-directory-security-1/
KB5037754: How to manage PAC Validation changes related to CVE-2024-26248 and CVE-2024-29056
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5037754-how-to-manage-pac-validation-changes-related-to-cve-2024-26248-and-cve-2024-29056-6e661d4f-799a-4217-b948-be0a1943fef1
KB5020805: How to manage Kerberos protocol changes related to CVE-2022-37967
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5020805-how-to-manage-kerberos-protocol-changes-related-to-cve-2022-37967-997e9acc-67c5-48e1-8d0d-190269bf4efb
Opt-out:
PAC Validation may be skipped (a security term meaning "not performed") in certain circumstances, including, but not limited to, the following scenarios:

If the service has TCB privilege (Act as part of the operating system). Generally, services running under the context of the SYSTEM account (such as SMB File Shares, or LDAP servers) have this privilege.

If the service is run from Task Scheduler.



Kerberos is completely different and in some ways opposite from NTLM.
NTLM is one-sided (only user credentials are involved), so the client produces its NTLM response purely from its password, which means NTLM response validation is done through the domain controller.
But the application server only has a Netlogon secure channel (based on its machine account) to its local domain controllers, and only those domain controllers have another secure channel (the trust password) to the client origin domain, so NTLM response validation needs to go through the whole chain – IIS contacts the local DC for "NTLM pass-through authentication", the trusting DC forwards that request to the trusted DC.
Meanwhile, Kerberos ticket validation is done entirely offline and without contacting the DC at all, because the client doesn't actually send any "user" credentials that would need to be validated – instead, the client obtains and sends a ticket specific to the service credentials of the application server.
So when cross-realm Kerberos is used, it is the client which needs to talk to KDCs (both its local KDC and the remote KDC) for ticket acquisition – first getting a 'cross-realm TGT' ticket from its local KDC (the trusted DC from IIS perspective), then using it to get an IIS service ticket from the trusting KDC (the local DC from IIS perspective) – whereas the server can validate that ticket offline against its locally-stored 'service account' key (derived from the machine/service account password for IIS; stored in a keytab file for Java).
The exception to the above is the AD-specific "PAC Validation" process that Greg Askew mentions, where the server may additionally request validation using (if I read the specs correctly) the same mechanism as NTLM pass-through validation does, from the remote KDC through its local KDC.
